# How to remove proguard file from inherit proguardFiles?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I have 2 buildTypes below:

```
debug {
    ...
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-dont-obfuscate.pro'
    ...
}

inhouse.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
inhouse {
    ...
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    println proguardFiles.toString()
    ...
}
```

I want my inhouse buildType inherited from debug (for other properties) but not to include proguard file proguard-rules-dont-obfuscate.pro as seen above. Unfortunately, after printing out the proguardFiles, it still has proguard-rules-dont-obfuscate.pro even though I didn't include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that proguardFiles does only proguardFiles.addAll internally. In order not to include proguard file from inherited buildTypes, I need to clear the proguardFiles list. Fortunately, I found setProguardFiles method, which does proguardFiles.clear() before setting. So the solution is add setProguardFiles(empty) before adding new proguard files.

```
inhouse.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
inhouse {
    ...
    List empty = new ArrayList<String>()
    setProguardFiles(empty)
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    println proguardFiles.toString()
    ...
}
```