# Do not include unused library to release apk

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I'm use in my android project `gson` library:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

I'm use it not in app module, but in my android library and this library added to project. Only several classes (groupA) used `gson`. Android library is common library and used in several android projects, but in current android project do not used classes from groupA.

I have in `build.gradle` of app:

```
android {
 ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

I build release apk and decompile classes.dex. I do not find classes groupA in apk. It's ok. `proguard` remove unused code.

Unfortunately I see `gson` classes. But why? Why `proguard` do not remove `gson` classes? `gson` really do not used in release version of project.

Comment: does https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies reveal the dependency that adds gson?

Comment: @sschrass, do not help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at the proguard file of gson which is included in each build: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg Recognize the remaining classes there?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand you. I have no any strings with `gson` at my proguard rules files.

Comment: So, for gson we have no solution?

Comment: Check this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768222/how-to-remove-proguard-file-from-inherit-proguardfiles

Answer (score 0):

> Why proguard do not remove gson classes?

Ask it:
Use the proguard option `-whyareyoukeeping` to find out why the gson classes are not removed

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#shrinkingoptions

Comment: I add to proguard rules files next line: `-whyareyoukeeping class com.google.gson.Gson`. Then build from command line: `gradle assembleRelease --info`. I search in log word `gson`, and found next: `com.google.gson.<some name>   is kept by a directive in the configuration.